# What role does Doctrine 2 take in an MVC ZF2 environment?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to teach myself ZF2 in conjunction with Doctrine 2.  I've completed both the Album tutorial and Blog Tutorial on Zend's website successfully.  Now I'm trying to go back and convert the Blog Tutorial to use Doctrine 2.  I believe I've successfully setup my config for doctrine and used DI to get it inside of my controller (WriteController.php) since I am able to dump the contents of it within my action.  I don't get any errors so long as I don't do anything with it.

My question is what roll does Doctrine take in the `Controller -> Service -> Mapper -> Backend` layered structure which was taught in the Blog tutorial? ([Reference To what I mean](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/review.html))

Also, I'm assuming `Backend` is referring to my Models.  Is this correct?

Would I just replace any references to `/Blog/Model/Post` with `/Blog/Entity/Blog`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Doctrine is the `Mapper`. And maybe we could say also the Service (through EntityRepository). But usually you will create your own Service Layer.

The `Backend` is not the entities it self. Entities in one way to map the several options of backend. As backend you can understand the several options of Relational Databases (Mysql, SqlServer, Oracle, etc) NoSql Databases (like MongoDB), file system and so on.

I didn't understand your last question. But when I use Doctrine I always create my entities in /MyModule/Entity namespace. While when I use the standart Zend/Db I always create in /MyModule/Model. I do that by standardizing matters.

Comment: I add a comment yesterday - I guess it didn't take.  So the Back end is considered the RDBMS, the Mapper contains the actual SQL (IE: doctrine), the Service should contain business logic (so given a set of data this would be where you might decide which Mapper Methods to call), and the controller is where it all starts?  Do I have this right?

Comment: Yes. But the Mapper isn't the SQL. When you are using a Mapper you create through it a way to deal with the Backend, even if you change the Backend. (IE: orm, dql in doctrine). The controllers cant call itself, they can be called by view: http requests or command line, but you got the idea, the controller calls the service layer.

Comment: So the Backend is not the database itself, just the language to use it (IE: Doctrine)?  

If I were to change my database (say to mongoDB) I should only have to change my Backend and the mapper should remain the same?  If this is true, I'm not sure I understand the difference between the Mapper and Backend.

Comment: No, it's not. In my opnion, Doctrine (the lib) and your Entities (and some others classes, like new Types, Functions you can create to deal with doctrine) is the Mapper. You are right, in a real world we will need to change the Mapper when we change the Backend. We will need to change some configs to reflect the new RDBMS, for instance. But note, the changes will be easier than creating the Backend from scratch using native SQL from a RDBMS to new one.